# Upgrading Joomla 1.5.x to 2.5.x without jUpgrade

Tags: php, joomla

I moved our site from an old host to a new host. We're now getting errors and I am unable to do an upgrade to 2.5 because I cannot access the website to install jUpgrade.

Is there a way to migrate to 2.5.x without jUpgrade?

Comment: do you have access to the FTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SP Upgrade (link [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/15609)) is another device (although commercial) similar to jUpgrade from 1.5.x to 2.5.x.

Without either jUpgrade or SPUpgrade I'm afraid you start from scratch - install a blank copy of Joomla 2.5 and manually install all the old components etc.

Remember though when upgrading from 1.5.x to 2.5.x not all extensions will be compatible!